# Notepad++ is unable to load langs.xml, why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++

Whenever I open NotePad++ the following error message appears:

> ---------------------------
>   Configurator
>   ---------------------------
>   Load langs.xml failed!
>   ---------------------------

That obviously means that there is also no syntax highlighting.

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Strangely, I had the same problem. And the interesting thing was the highlighting worked when I selected the language manually. Anyways, the accepted answer seems to fix the problem completely.

Comment: This happens to me occasionally. And I lose my settings as well. This is going for a few years at least.

Comment: It happens occasionally. Each time I follow the steps in the [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/67143/66293), but it's still annoying. In my latest attempt, I denied myseld write rights to langs.xml, so hopingly the file doesn't get truncated now.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Somehow, your `langs.xml` has errors in it. Perhaps while exploring various Notepad++ options you accidentally made unintended changes to it. That's what happened to me.

Go to the installation folder for Notepad++ and rename `langs.xml` to `langs.xml.bad`. Then, in that same folder, find `langs.model.xml`, make a copy of it, and rename the copy to `langs.xml`. **DO NOT** simply rename the file or you will not have it available the next time you need it.

also replace this file in the folder `C:\users\(user)\appdata\roaming\notepad++`

You will want to then compare the **langs.xml** to **langs.xml.bad** and see if there is anything legitimate that you want back.

If you are missing the **langs.model.xml** file, you can [download the current version from the svn repo](http://notepad-plus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/notepad-plus/trunk/PowerEditor/src/langs.model.xml?view=log).

Comment: Worked here, too. As an aside, I'd mention the fact that my langs.xml file had no "errors" as such.. it was blank! Size, zero. Sadly, I wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour which caused it to be wiped clean.

Comment: Me too. Zero, too.

Comment: My langs.xml looked like it had been truncated after like the 30th line for some reason.  Rob3C's fix worked great!

Comment: Mine was zero too. Are all you zero-byte file guys on Windows 7 x64, perchance? I wonder if there's a Notepad++ bug around this. I swear I haven't mucked around with the settings..

Comment: Mine was zero too. This is under Windows 2003.

Comment: Mine was zero - xp/32bit - maybe wiped after a crash

Comment: Mine was zero length too. Windows 7, x64.

Comment: I also had a truncated langs.xml. But this fix worked like a charm.

Comment: mine was zero length too, win7, x64.  seems like it started happening after an update (or maybe a failed update?)

This worked great.

Comment: Same here, mine got truncated somwhere in the middle of the file. Could it be some kind of crash white writing the preferences?

Comment: Solved!!, You are the best!, Half the file was missing!

Comment: This solves it (+1), but I am very sure I did not edit this file or play with options before the error appeared.

Comment: Windows 7, x64 here; mine was truncated at about line 50.

Comment: 0 length on Windows 7 32-bit here, so not just a 64-bit version problem.

Comment: Yeah, this solves it, but it's the second time I have to do it, so I expect to have to repeat the procedure in near future. Maybe I should setup a scheduled task to fix it everyday?

Comment: Yup Win7/32 here and the same issue.  Only things I'd changed with respect to languages were file extension associations.

Comment: Win7/64 here. My langs.xml file appeared to be perfectly valid XML. Diffing against langs.model.xml produced a few differences, but it looked like they were all possibly the result of upgrades, as I don't remember making any of the changes. However, even after copying all the differences into langs.xml, it still failed. Replacing langs.xml with a copy of langs.model.xml still didn't help. I ended up just deleting langs.xml, and it seems to stop the error from happening, though there's no syntax highlighting. This is Notepad++ v5.9

Comment: I ended up reinstalling.

Comment: The newest version of Notepad++ automatically restores langs.xml if you delete the file. You may have to look in your AppData/Roaming/Notepadd++ folder.

Comment: After my laptop crash and reboot, I had this problem (the langs.xml contains all NULL character). By delete or renaming these 2 files, it works !

Comment: Also had to do this for stylers.xml.

Comment: Since Notepad++ has added the option for storing settings in cloud storage i.e. DropBox, OneDrive, GoogleDrive, make sure that if you have the Settings -> Preferences -> Clouds -> Settings on cloud option turned on you update the langs.xml file in the Notepad++ directory on the root of your cloud storage folder.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem but I had to replace the langs.xml in the following path to fix it.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

For those on a current Windows release:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++
```

Comment: This worked for me. The file had been truncated, so was invalid XML.

Comment: This one worked for me, Windows7 64bit. In the installation folder (C:/Program Files(x86)/Notepad++ was the langs.model.xml but no langs.xml.

Thanks

Comment: Same here.  First tried the accepted answer.  There was no langs.xml in the install folder, but there was in this roaming directory.  Suggest first finding which situation fits you by locating the corrupted langs.xml, then copying the model into its place.

Comment: This worked for me. I used Notepad++ zip version (rather than installer). I think installer ensures existency of xml files is Roaming directory, so without installer one has to copy them manually. It has nothing to do with XML corruption.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error message, but a different issue - the langs.xml file was OK. Replacing it with langs.model.xml did not fix the problem.

To fix the problem, I had to open langs.xml in Notepad++ (running as Admin on Windows7 to be able to save in ProgramFiles). Then, from the `Encoding` menu, I saw the file is saved as ANSI. The XML declaration specifies 1252 charset. So I re-encoded the file by selecting `Encoding` -> `Character sets` -> `Western european` -> `Windows-1252`. Then I made a small change to the file and re-saved it.

I suspect this is related to the default codepage of the system.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers did not work for me.

Uninstalling and reinstalling *npp* did the trick.

Comment: Yes, in my case the files langs.xml didn´t even exist.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This answer was taken from a rejected edit and it was **not** written by me:</sub>

Not a full proof solution as it can happen again.

"Do not use environment variable %APPDATA%" can be selected on Windows 7 installations, but seems to be ignored. `Langs.xml` seems to always be put in `%APPDATA%`. (Is this confusion the cause of the bug?)

Copy the new `%APPDATA%\Langs.xml` to `%APPDATA%\Langs.model.xml` and put a copy in `Program Files\Notepad++`.

Copy `%APPDATA%\Langs.model.xml` or `ProgramFiles\Notepad++\Langs.model.xml` to `%APPDATA%\Langs.xml` if the problem occurs again – not foolproof but it's a workaround.

A foolproof solution would be to fix the bug causing `Langs.xml` to be corrupted.

Comment: No, the file will never be placed directly under `%APPDATA%`, instead it may be in the `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Notepad++` folder, or in the root folder of the application. Also, you suggest to copy the broken `langs.xml` on top of `langs.model.xml`. *do not do that, it will break permanently*, instead, copy the other way around, as suggested in the accepted answer and leave the `langs.model.xml`, which is untouched, where it was.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used the ZIP version (no installer). Renaming files and reinstalling did not work for me.

Try running the exe with "Run As Administrator" and then say Yes when it asks to fix the config.xml file. This worked for me.