# load langs.xml failed also after fix

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I have the same error as stated on: [Notepad++ is unable to load langs.xml, why?](https://superuser.com/questions/67128/notepad-load-langs-xml-failed). I have also applied the fix listed there. I delete the langs.xml file. Then when I reboot notepad++.exe a new langs.xml is created from the langs.model.xml file. However, after I reboot my computer the langs.xml file is corrupted again. It is completely empty.

Does anyone know what is causing the deletion of the langs.xml file? I noticed the problem shortly after using windows 7 64 bit, and on two seperate computers.

Comment: Have you got the latest version of notepad++?

Comment: Same happens to me ever since I use notepad++ , ALWAYS, with the latest version of course.

Answer (score 2):

solved on win7:

> In addition to nicktatham's info,
>   langs.xml might not be empty. it might
>   be incomplete like mine was (83 lines
>   vs 283) WINDOWS 7 / VISTA MODIFIED
>   INSTRUCTIONS After deleting the
>   langs.xml, right click notepad++.exe
>   and run as administrator. without
>   doing this the application cannot
>   write the langs.xml file.

thanks to

[sourceforge solution no.5.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/3489806)

Answer (score 1):

try to copy proper lang.xml files from c:\Program Files\Notepad++ to  %appdata%\notepad++ 
it works fine for me